# Does the Hubble expansion cause apparent friction?

Tags: friction, space-expansion

When you have a peculiar velocity (i.e. a velocity that is *not* due to the expansion of the universe) your current comoving frame (i.e. the frame of reference relative to the stuff directly around you) is always changing.  Your new frames always have some velocity in the direction of your travel relative to your old frames (at least as long as the Hubble constant is positive, but this is the case in the current universe and AFAIK is expected to never change).  If you measure your velocity always relative to your current comoving frame, your velocity should decrease therefore.

Does this "Hubble friction" (in quotes because that term is already in use for something else) actually exist (and is not canceled out perfectly by e.g. the acceleration due to expansion or something) and how big is it.  I tried to derive the formula myself, but my understanding of this concept is too bad to be able to do it and I also didn't find anything searching the web.

Comment: It sounds like you're imagining that reference frames are made of some solid matter that can rub against each other. But they're not made of anything at all. They're not physical objects.

Comment: @D.Halsey I know that their not. What I mean is: Imagine some place far away. The stuff there is moving away from us according to Hubble's law. If you now have a large velocity in that direction, you will eventually reach it. But as we already have established the local "normal" velocity there is very different to where you started.  Now measuring from this new frame of reference you have to subtract the velocity of the new frame of reference from your velocity in the old one to get the velocity in the new one. This velocity will be smaller=>Something like friction happened.

Comment: Once you get to your far away location, it will no longer appear to be a smooth expansion. It will be dependent on what's going on locally, just like it is here. Hubble expansion is only a useful way to look at things over a very large scale and isn't relevant to what's going on at small scales.

Comment: @D.Halsey I know that the effect is of negligible magnitude and even that only over billions of years, but it still feels like an interesting phenomenon.

Comment: Why should there be any friction if there's nothing physically rubbing together?

Comment: "*apparent* friction":  I know that there is no friction, just that it seems so.  In "Hubble friction" there is no matter too for example.

Comment: The physical situation is that there are nonuniformities and random motions everywhere, but you only notice the ones that are close to you. Farther away, everything appears more uniform. How does the concept of friction apply to that?

Comment: Then ignore the term "friction".  My question is then:  What is the delta v per time with a given velocity and Hubble constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect is real, and happens for the reason you describe, but it isn't a frictional (dissipative) process; no forces are involved. Peebles mentions it in Principles of Physical Cosmology and calls it "velocity sorting". E. A. Milne, who may have been the first to discuss it in the 1930s, also described it as a sorting process.

Suppose your object is at the origin at time $t$ and it has velocity $v$ relative to local inertial coordinates, which is also its peculiar velocity. A short time $dt$ later (short enough that it's still on the local inertial patch), its velocity is still $v$, but its location is $v\,dt$; its peculiar velocity at time $t+dt$ is therefore $v - H\,v\,dt$. That argument gives $dv/dt = -Hv$ (for small $v$).

Comment: what do you mean when you say that the effect is a kinematic one and not frictional? @benrg

Comment: @vengaq To be honest I've never quite understood what "kinematic" means. I reworded it.

Answer (score 1):

The relativistic momentum $p=mv\gamma$ relative to a local observer comoving with the Hubble flow is inversely proportional to the growth of the scale factor $a$:

$$\frac{p_0}{a(t)} = \frac{p(t)}{a_0}$$

With photons that relation also holds, but since their $v$ is constant the frequency decreases instead in order to shrink their momentum.

Comment: Thanks for the formula!  Applying it yields $$p' = -Hp$$ or – if v << c and m=const – $$a = -Hv$$.